# Xamarin.Android NavigationTabStrip

Tags: xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I want to implement the NavigationTabStrip (https://github.com/martijn00/NavigationTabStripXamarin) to my app, but I don't know how. I've seen also the original project, but I'm new in this world. Has anyone a project to help me to implement this? Or is there anyone that knows how to do that? I'm trying to create a TabLayout in material design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Easiest way to do it would be like this :

http://camposha.info/source/xamarin-android-swipe-tabs-viewpager-fragments-images-actionbartabs/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-sliding-tab-layout-interface-using-xamarin-android-using-visual-studio/

The code is in xamarin so it would be an easy implementation for you!

Goodluck!

**UPDATE:**

The code for your activities Axml file :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
   >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:id="@+id/tabs"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:tabGravity="fill"
  app:tabMode="fixed"
   />
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/frame_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for your Activities cs file:

```
 public class GoogleMapsActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private Fragment MapsFragment;
    private Fragment ListFragment;
    private TabLayout allTabs;
    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.your_activity);
        bindAllWidgets();
        setupTabLayout();
        setUpToolbar();
    }
  void setUpToolbar()
    {
        #region "Tool bar"
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.SetTitleTextColor(ResourcesCompat.GetColor(Resources, Resource.Color.colorRedText, null));
        Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, null);
        upArrow.SetColorFilter(Color.ParseColor(Resources.GetString(Resource.Color.colorRedText)), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.Title = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.toolbar_title_dhl_service_points);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        #endregion
    }
    private void setupTabLayout()
    {
        allTabs.AddTab(allTabs.NewTab().SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.google_maps_page_title_map)), true);
        allTabs.AddTab(allTabs.NewTab().SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.google_maps_page_title_list)));
    }

    private void bindAllWidgets()
    {
        allTabs = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        allTabs.TabSelected += AllTabs_TabSelected;
    }
    private void AllTabs_TabSelected(object sender, TabSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tab = e.Tab;
        setCurrentTabFragment(tab.Position);
    }
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        fm = FragmentManager;
        ft = fm.BeginTransaction();
        if (fragment == MapsFragment)
        {
            if (MapsFragment == null)
            {
                MapsFragment = new PoSLocationMapView(this);
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.frame_container, MapsFragment, "MapsFragment");

            }
            else
            {
                ft.Detach(FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("ListFragment"));
                ft.Attach(MapsFragment);
            }
        }
        else if (fragment == ListFragment)
        {
            if (ListFragment == null)
            {
                ListFragment = new ServicePointDHLList(this);
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.frame_container, ListFragment, "ListFragment");
            }
            else
            {
                ft.Detach(FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("MapsFragment"));
                ft.Attach(ListFragment);
            }
        }
        ft.SetTransition(FragmentTransit.FragmentOpen);
        ft.Commit();

    }
    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition)
    {
        switch (tabPosition)
        {
            case 0:
                replaceFragment(MapsFragment);
                break;
            case 1:
                replaceFragment(ListFragment);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the first but in material design? P.S Thank you! :D

Comment: This will actually take your theme by default you don't have to worry about it

Comment: Sorry but, in the  fragment_sample.axml file, I got an error of SlidingTabLayoutTutorial.SlidingTabScrollView, it doesn't exist..I'm gonna crazy..

Comment: Which link are you using Sir ?

Comment: And..Maybe I'm wrong but It doesn't take the theme, I've set a Material Theme in the Manifest but it doesn't work :\

Comment: I'm using the first link

Comment: Try the Second Link ? or maybe wait I will update my code give me a second

Comment: I prefer using the first one, It's closer to what I want

Comment: Yeah I can try now, no probls

Comment: Should I create an activity for every tab I have? Because I'm totally new in this world and I don't know how to do this..

Comment: You need one activity and two fragments

Comment: God..I can't understand all of this..not even how to modify your code for my app..I'm a fool ahaha..

Comment: Do you use Skype ?

Comment: Yeah, or TeamSpeak or Discord

Comment: Gimme your skype

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it is more clearly.

https://github.com/ahoefling/TabStrip/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Xamarin.Forms..can I use the first one anyway?